# Why do implicit conversion member functions overloading work by return type, while it is not allowed for normal functions?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, implicit-conversion

C++ does not allow polymorphism for methods based on their return type. However, when overloading an implicit conversion member function this seems possible.

Does anyone know why? I thought operators are handled like methods internally.

Edit: Here's an example:

```
struct func {
    operator string() { return "1";}
    operator int() { return 2; }
};

int main( ) {
    int x    = func(); // calls int version
    string y = func(); // calls string version
    double d = func(); // calls int version
    cout << func() << endl; // calls int version
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm not sure what you mean by overloading by return type.

Comment: Would you provide an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conversion operators are not really considered different overloads and they are not called based on *their return type*. The compiler will only use them when it **has to** (when the type is incompatible and should be converted) or when explicitly asked to use one of them with a cast operator.

Semantically, what your code is doing is to declare several **different** type conversion operators and **not overloads of a single operator**.

Comment: "_Conversion operators are not really considered different overloads_" They are not overloaded functions at all: they have different names.

Answer (score 3):

That's not return type. That's type conversion.

Consider: func() creates an object of type func. There is no ambiguity as to what method (constructor) will be invoked.

The only question which remains is if it is possible to cast it to the desired types. You provided the compiler with appropriate conversion, so it is happy.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a technical reason to prevent overloading of functions on the result types. This is done in some languages like Ada for instance, but in the context of C++ which has also implicit conversions (and two kind of them), the utility is reduced, and the interactions of both features would quickly leads to ambiguities.

Note that you can use the fact that implicit conversions are user definable to simulate overloading on result type:

```
class CallFProxy;
CallFProxy f(int);

class CallFProxy {
   int myParameter;
   CallFProxy(int i) : myParameter(i) {}
public:
   operator double() { std::cout << "Calling f(int)->double\n"; return myParameter; }
   operator string() { std::cout << "Calling f(int)->string\n"; return "dummy"; }
};
```

Comment: "_There isn't really a technical reason to prevent overloading of functions on the result types._" Well, the "technical reason" is that a function call has a well-defined type in C++ (and not in Ada). Almost all expressions in C++ have a well-defined type and meaning, except (1) meaningless sub-expressions in a member function call in `o.mf()`, `o.mf` is not a valid sub-expression and does not have a type (if `mf` is a member function, not a data member); (2) address of an overloaded function, f.ex. `&std::cos` (`cos(float)`, `cos(double)`, ...?)

Comment: (...) In C++, to determine the meaning of an expression, you can start with the inner subexpressions, determine their meaning, and continue all the way up (with the exceptions I have just mentioned). In Ada, the meaning of `read()` can depend on the type of `var` in: `var := read();`. Note that `read();` is not a valid statement: there is no expression-statement in Ada. You need to either call a procedure (**not** a function!), or do an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Overload resolution chooses between multiple candidate functions. In this process, the return type of candidates is indeed not considered. However, in the case of conversion operators the "return type" is critically important in determining whether that operator is a candidate at all.

Comment: These candidate functions have different return types and also **different names**. They are not overloaded, even less overloaded on the return type.

Comment: @curiousguy: Conversion functions can be overloaded on cv-qualification, and template-ness.

Comment: This is correct, but in this particular example, they are not overloaded.